# How do I create a method that adds a dash after every vowel?

Tags: java, string

```
static char[] vowelArray = {'e', 'i', 'u', 'o', 'a'};

    public static String insertDashAfterWovel(String input){

    char[] tmp=input.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
        if (tmp[i]== vowelArray[i]){
            tmp[i]+='-';
            return tmp.toString();
        }
    }
    return "";
```

The method I made doesn't work. How do I make it so that it adds a dash after every detected vowel and returns the string like in the example below? I made a testclass for this method to verify whether I'm right.

"gladiator" should return "gla-di-a-to-r"

Comment: "doesn't work" in what way doesn't it work? What example inputs does your test class give it, what is the expected and actual output? What did you find when you stepped through with a debugger?

Comment: First of all, you are using the same index to iterate over the string as in the vowel array, your for loop should not be checking whether the actual string character is at the same index, but rather independent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expression like this:

```
String str = "gladiator";  // your input string
str = str.replaceAll("([aeiou])", "$1-");
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: I love the solution even though it doesn't help OP with their snippet

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Could you explain the $1- part? Is that some sort of formatting tool?

Comment: But it did help me. I just had to ditch the vowelArray and that's it.

Comment: $1 means the first portion of the regular expression which is ([aeiou]), we only have one portion, some complex regular expression has multiple portions. Detailed info can be found at: https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html

Comment: @lapartman $1 used to refer something that is matched for replacing, in this example one of the vowels so we replace each vowel with own ($1) and a dash.

Comment: Thank you guys. This really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 static char[] vowelArray = {'e', 'i', 'u', 'o', 'a'};

 public static String insertDashAfterWovel(String input){

    char[] tmp=input.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < vowelArray.length; i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<tmp.length;j++){
            if (vowelArray[i]==tmp[j]){
                input=input.replace(input.substring(j,j+1),(input.substring(j,j+1)+"-"));
                break;
             }   
        }
    }
    return input;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the poster's question is:

> The method I made doesn't work. How do I make it so that it adds a dash after every detected vowel and
>   returns the string like in the example below? "gladiator" should
>   return "gla-di-a-to-r"

I am providing a working example that most closely resembles the original method.

```
static char[] vowelArray = {'e', 'i', 'u', 'o', 'a'};

public static String insertDashAfterVowel(String input){

    char[] tmp=input.toCharArray();
    String newString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
        newString += tmp[i];
        if (new String(vowelArray).indexOf(tmp[i]) != -1){
            newString += "-";            
        }
    }
    return newString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (Character.toString(tmp[i]).matches("[eiuoa]"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using simply a for loop, a foreach loop would do the job then create a string variable to contain and replace the vowel with a vowel plus a dash

Somthing like:

Instead of just a, it becomes a_. Hope it was helpfull